# 127.0.0.1 works in Chrome but doesn't work in Edge

Tags: windows, rest, google-chrome, go, postman

I built a simple web API using Golang and need to test it.

First I tried to call APIs in Chrome: http://127.0.0.1:8080/balances - works perfectly.

And I tried to call in Postman: http://127.0.0.1:8080/balances - doesn't work - couldn't find the web API. So I changed to http://localhost:8080/balances and it works.

Thought it's something with Postman, so tried on Microsoft Edge. 127.0.0.1 doesn't work and localhost works.

So the only browser 127.0.0.1 works is Chrome.

Not sure what's going on here. What should I do to make 127.0.0.1 work in all of web clients including Edge and Postman?

Comment: There's no question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Check proxy bypass settings in Edge make sure it's set to proxy bypass for localhost. Next check `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and make sure the localhost entry is present.

Comment: Where is bypass settings in Edge?
I tried edit hosts, but it doesn't work.